# Updating Hive box from a background process in the main function in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a a background function that listens to incoming sim card messages and updates a hive box with the message. However I cannot perform Hive crud operations on this background function. I have read about using Isolates to pass the crud operations to main. How do I do this.

My crud operation is of this fashion, adding the text to a list of texts
final box = Boxes.getMessages();
box.add(inbox);